# Provide dependency file to a Spring app deployed with Docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, tomcat, dockerfile

I have a Spring application as a war file deployed in Tomcat. All is done with a docker file. While running the app, I get an exception for this missing file `Script resource ste/SteCommon.groovy: not found at scripts/ste/SteCommon.groovy` and Script `resource ste/SteCommon.groovy: not found at /home/vcap/cloudsuite/config/scripts/ste/SteCommon.groovy`.

I see in docker file there is an env variable with the path `/home/vcap/cloudsuite/config`, how can I put a file in it?

Below the dockerfile:

```
# Use the official Tomcat image as the base image
FROM tomcat:9-jdk17

# Set environment variables
ENV JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE='{jre: {version: 1.17+}}' \
JBP_CONFIG_TOMCAT='{ tomcat: { version: 9.0.+ }, context_path: /cloudsuite-car/maker }' \
CLOUDSUITE_BASE_DIR='/home/vcap/cloudsuite/config' \
CLOUDSUITE_PROFILE_DIR='/home/vcap/cloudsuite/config' \
CLOUDSUITE_DATA_DIR='/home/vcap/cloudsuite/data' \
CLOUDSUITE_LOG_DIR='/home/vcap/cloudsuite/log' \
CLOUDSUITE_DATA_SHARED='/home/vcap/cloudsuite/data' \
JDBC_DRIVERCLASSNAME='org.postgresql.Driver' \
JDBC_URL='jdbc:postgresql://car-postgres:5432/car' \
JDBC_USERNAME='postgres' \
JDBC_PASSWORD='postgres' \
CLOUDSUITE_LOG_LEVEL='TRACE' \
AUTHENTICATION_ACTIVE='false' \
digsig.validation.validationContext.qualificationSeverity='info'

# Set Java options
ENV JAVA_OPTS='-Duser.timezone=UTC -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -    Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=5000'

# Remove the default Tomcat webapps (optional)
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*

# Copy your WAR file to the webapps folder of the Tomcat container
COPY cloudsuite-car#maker.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war

# Expose the default Tomcat port (optional, as the base image already does this)
EXPOSE 8080
```

I am not sure I can provide it.

Comment: Why? Just ditch the tomcat deployment and run the embedded server that comes with Spring Boot. This is a lot easier for your docker container. Anyway apparently your cloudsuite configuration is wrong (or the files that it needs aren't in your container). This doesn't really have anything to do with your spring boot application.

Comment: how can I put the file in /home/vcap/cloudsuite/config, that is the path that docker wants?